# Para que serve o comando CREATE VIEW do MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber para que serve o comando `CREATE VIEW` do MySQL?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`CREATE VIEW` cria um objeto do tipo `VIEW` no seu banco de dados.

Uma *View* é uma transformação em cima de uma ou mais tabelas que se comporta como uma tabela. Normalmente é somente-leitura (não é possível nem inserir, nem alterar, nem excluir linhas dela).

Exemplo:

```
CREATE VIEW MinhaView AS
SELECT COLUNA2, COLUNA4, COLUNA6 
FROM TABELA 
WHERE COLUNA1 = 1;
```

Você pode selecionar dados diretamente sobre a *View* após a criação:

```
SELECT * FROM MinhaView;
```

O resultado será equivalente ao `SELECT` que faz parte do corpo da *View*.

**EDIT**

Exemplo perguntado por comentário:

```
CREATE VIEW MinhaView2 AS
SELECT CONCAT(NOME, ' ', SOBRENOME) AS NOME_COMPLETO, COLUNA2, COLUNA3, COLUNA4
FROM TABELA_COM_NOME;
```

Comment: eu consigo criar um coluna e setar um valor para ela? exemplo, pegar o valor de uma coluna nome e o valor de uma coluna chama sobrenome e setar esses dois valores em uma unica coluna?

Comment: Sim, consegue. Vou colocar o exemplo pra você.

Comment: Esse CREATE VIEW eu uso ele toda vez antes de fazer a consulta para criar a view correto?

Comment: Não. Usa-se só uma vez pra criar o objeto. Depois basta o `select` em cima da *View* pra obter os resultados.

Comment: Mas se eu adicionar um novo nome essa view não vai estar atualizada, ou seja eu uso ela depois do insert?

Comment: @LeandroCosta Neste caso, você vai precisar alterar a *View*. Isso pode ser feito ou usando `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`, ou usando `ALTER VIEW`. A sintaxe é a mesma do `CREATE VIEW`.

Answer (score 10):

Serve para criar uma 'tabela de somente leitura'/tabela virtual que é baseada em consultas. Pode funcionar como um atalho para consultas longas.

Ao inves de colocar esse consulta em vários lugares no código

```
SELECT p.nome, c.categoria_descricao, t.tipo_descricao FROM produtos as p
INNER JOIN categorias as c ON  p.id_categoria = c.id_categoria
INNER JOIN tipo as t ON  p.id_tipo = t.id_tipo
```

Poderia criar uma view para trazer a descrição e o tipo de produto, simplificando sua chamada.

```
CREATE view produto_simplificado as
SELECT p.nome, c.categoria_descricao, t.tipo_descricao FROM produtos as p
INNER JOIN categorias as c ON  p.id_categoria = c.id_categoria
INNER JOIN tipo as t ON  p.id_tipo = t.id_tipo
```

depois bastaria chamar dessa forma

```
SELECT * FROM produto_simplificado
```

Comment: Foi útil para mim.

Answer (score 4):

Uma citação retirada do post do IMaster ([Trabalhando com VIEWS no MYSQL](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/8765/mysql/trabalhando-com-views-no-mysql/))

> Uma View é um objeto que pertence a um banco de dados, definida
>   baseada em declarações SELECT´s, retornando uma determinada
>   visualização de dados de uma ou mais tabelas. Esses objetos são
>   chamados por vezes de “virtual tables”, formada a partir de outras
>   tabelas que por sua vez são chamadas de “based tables” ou ainda outras
>   Views. E alguns casos, as Views são atualizáveis e podem ser alvos de
>   declaração INSERT, UPDATE e DELETE, que na verdade modificam sua
>   “based tables”.
>
> Os benefícios da utilização de Views, além dos já salientados, são:
>
> Uma View pode ser utilizada, por exemplo, para retornar um valor
>   baseado em um identificador de registro; Pode ser utilizada para
>   promover restrições em dados para aumentar a segurança dos mesmos e
>   definir políticas de acesso em nível de tabela e coluna. Podem ser
>   configurados para mostrar colunas diferentes para diferentes usuários
>   do banco de dados; Pode ser utilizada com um conjunto de tabelas que
>   podem ser unidas a outros conjuntos de tabelas com a utilização de
>   JOIN´s ou UNION.

Comment: É preferível fazer exemplos e explicações ao invés de citações e links externos.

Answer (score 3):

Uma View é uma query SELECT que fica salva no banco de dados para ser usada depois. Quando precisar dos dados da View em qualquer contexto, basta usar o nome da mesma, que será como um sub-SELECT no ponto em que o nome da View for usado.